# Using Microsoft custom translation (free tier), we could build a customized model but could we test the model?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

We are trying the Microsoft custom translation. 
We follow the [quick start document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/quickstart-build-deploy-custom-model) and we succeeded in building a model.

However, it seems we could train the model but **not** deploy the model using the [free plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/).

In this case, how could we use the trained model? Is it possible to download it and try it locally?

Edit: 
I am using a dictionary with only one word. And I didn't see the system test result for the model. Is it expected?

Answer (score 0):

The free tier is to test and view the results, by doing so you will be able to check what is to be the output of a deployed model to see if it would be efficient or not so that you'd decide whether you want to proceed in deploying it or not!

You can view the `System Test Results` by selecting a project, then select the models tab of that project, locate the model you want to use and finally select the test tab as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/custom-translator/how-to-view-system-test-results)

This allows you to try the service and test its efficiency without deploying it, but if you want to deploy the model you will have to switch to a paid tier.

Comment: I didn't find the test tab. So in the end, what's the purpose of the training feature in the free tier? IMHO, I would like to at least test some very simple cases by myself, before paying the money.